Using 'this' in a getter/setter defined on a class field property. How to define class field getters/setters on child properties?
The issue in question relates to human readability and data organization. I would like to assign getters and setters as children of class field properties, however I can't get this to reference the class prototype data. I think this is the same problem solved by using self in a class constructor, but applied to class fields instead. Is there a comparable solution for class fields that would keep these definitions out of the constructor?
This is the format I would like to achieve. The constructor is not invoked because external data is not required for these field definitions. This throws a recursion error.


class data_controller {
  // class fields
  id = 12;
  a = 10;
  b = 20;
  // log data entries
  log = {
    entry: {
      get a() {
        return {
          id: this.id,
          value: this.a,
          label: 'a',
        };
      },
      get b() {
        return {
          id: this.id,
          value: this.b,
          label: 'b',
        };
      },
    },
  };
  // update data
  update = {
    set a(value) {
      this.a = value;
    },
    set b(value) {
      this.b = value;
    },
  };
}
// class usage
const data = new data_controller();
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);
data.update.a = 50;
data.update.b = 60;
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);



This is the format using 'self' and the constructor. I would like to keep the constructor free of these definitions.


class data_controller {
  // class fields
  id = 12;
  a = 10;
  b = 20;
  log = {};
  update = {};
  constructor() {
    self = this;
    // log data entries
    this.log.entry = {
      get a() {
        return {
          id: self.id,
          value: self.a,
          label: 'a',
        };
      },
      get b() {
        return {
          id: self.id,
          value: self.b,
          label: 'b',
        };
      },
    };
    // update data
    this.update = {
      set a(value) {
        self.a = value;
      },
      set b(value) {
        self.b = value;
      },
    };
  }
}
// class usage
const data = new data_controller();
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);
data.update.a = 50;
data.update.b = 60;
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);



This is a format which keeps the constructor free of definitions but does not implement the getter/setter class usage.


class data_controller {
  // class fields
  id = 12;
  a = 10;
  b = 20;
  // log data entries
  log = {
    entry: {
      a: () => {
        return {
          id: this.id,
          value: this.a,
          label: 'a',
        };
      },
      b: () => {
        return {
          id: this.id,
          value: this.b,
          label: 'b',
        };
      },
    },
  };
  // update data
  update = {
    a: (value) => {
      this.a = value;
    },
    b: (value) => {
      this.b = value;
    },
  };
}
// class usage
const data = new data_controller();
console.log(data.log.entry.a());
console.log(data.log.entry.b());
data.update.a(50);
data.update.b(60);
console.log(data.log.entry.a());
console.log(data.log.entry.b());



I believe I could also solve this issue by making the class field organization flat, but I would like to maintain multi-level structures.

"The issue in question relates to human readability and data organization. I would like to maintain multi-level structures." - then you should use multiple classes! If you have identified separate parts of your class, each with its own behaviour, then they do not belong inside a single class.

The entire idea of providing a controlled getter setter access of a data instance's properties immediately renders useless with the chosen approach/implementation where the thought to be protected class fields id, a, b are left  totally unprotected in the open at first place …class data_controller { id = 12; a = 10; b = 20; /* more code */ }. The same accounts for both, the log.entry getter and update setter properties; theirs implementations too are unprotected. Providing protected access only makes sense in case one can ensure covered protection all along the access path.

@UnchainedLight ... after you having had to take the above critique, I want to draw your attention to a late provided answer of mine which explains and shows how a bullet-proof  implementation of your example code actually had to look like.

You can add a reference to the containing object in the nested objects. It's parent in the code below. Then you can use this.parent to go up a level.


class data_controller {
  // class fields
  id = 12;
  a = 10;
  b = 20;
  // log data entries
  log = {
    entry: {
      parent: this,
      get a() {
        return {
          id: this.parent.id,
          value: this.parent.a,
          label: 'a',
        };
      },
      get b() {
        return {
          id: this.parent.id,
          value: this.parent.b,
          label: 'b',
        };
      },
    },
  };
  // update data
  update = {
    parent: this,
    set a(value) {
      this.parent.a = value;
    },
    set b(value) {
      this.parent.b = value;
    },
  };
}
// class usage
const data = new data_controller();
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);
data.update.a = 50;
data.update.b = 60;
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);




Thank you, that makes sense. I did mess around with this and something was going wrong. I'll take another look. I see now, I was defining parent for both 'log' and 'entry,' thinking that I had to pass the reference to each object. I don't quite understand why the 'entry' scoped 'this' goes to the class and not to 'log'?

It goes to the entry, since that's the object containing the properties.

Remember that this is not specific to classes. Classes are mostly just syntactic sugar for objects and prototypes.

Follow-up that I was also not using this.parent and tried to use parent directly. I understand why this was one of the problems.

barmar - I did not phrase my question well but your comments helped me understand. I think this is correct: When 'this' is used during value assignment for a nested class field property, the 'this' does reference the instantiated class object. However the getters/setters are functions, and so when 'this' is used it references the parent object. Therefore, no matter how many levels deep the child object is, I can always define parent = this on that child and still get a reference to the instantiated class object. Then use that parent definition in a getter/setter on that same child object.

For the record: you don't really need class syntax. Here is a classfree object oriented version with this completely out of the way:


function dataControllerFactory() {
  return function(id, a, b) {
    return Object.freeze({
      log: {
        get a() { return { id, value: a, label: `a` } },
        get b() { return { id, value: b, label: `b` } },
      },
      update: {
        set a(value) { a = value; }, 
        set b(value) { b = value; }, 
      }
    });
  };
}

const DataCTOR = dataControllerFactory();
const myDataController = DataCTOR('itsMe', 21, 42);
console.log(`**initial`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.log.a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.log.b));
myDataController.update.a = myDataController.log.a.value * 2;
myDataController.update.b = myDataController.log.b.value * 2;
console.log(`**updated`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.log.a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.log.b));



Which may (dependent on your intentions with it) be simplified to:


function dataControllerFactory() {
  return function(id, a, b) {
    return Object.freeze({
      get a() { return { id, value: a, label: `a` } },
      get b() { return { id, value: b, label: `b` } },
      set a(value) { a = value; }, 
      set b(value) { b = value; }, });
  };
}

const DataCTOR = dataControllerFactory();
const myDataController = DataCTOR('itsMe', 21, 42);
console.log(`**initial`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.b));
myDataController.a = myDataController.a.value * 2;
myDataController.b = myDataController.b.value * 2;
console.log(`**updated`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.a));
console.log(JSON.stringify(myDataController.b));




I would suggest to refactor this into multiple separate classes, but if you insist on nesting…

I would like to keep the constructor free of these definitions.

You can also place them in some other method and just call that from your constructor. Or you can even create the objects using methods:


class DataController {
  // class fields
  id = 12;
  a = 10;
  b = 20;
  log = this._createLog();
  update = this._createUpdate();

  _createLog() {
    const self = this;
    return {
      entry: {
        get a() {
          return {
            id: self.id,
            value: self.a,
            label: 'a',
          };
        },
        get b() {
          return {
            id: self.id,
            value: self.b,
            label: 'b',
          };
        },
      }
    };
  }
  _createUpdate() {
    const self = this;
    return {
      set a(value) {
        self.a = value;
      },
      set b(value) {
        self.b = value;
      },
    };
  }
}
// class usage
const data = new DataController();
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);
data.update.a = 50;
data.update.b = 60;
console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);




Like with @Barmar 's code, the above one provides rather a patch than a real solution to the many underlying faults which are a direct result of the OP's originally chosen base design/approach.

@PeterSeliger choosing a better design is what the first sentence in this answer is about :-) This answer was just supposed to show that avoiding a constructor is not really a limitation

You are right, even though I read this sentence, I lost it when seeing this patchy code coming from you. Please accept my apologies.

Referring to my above comment which criticizes the OP's approach in its entirety ...

The entire idea of providing a controlled getter setter access of a data instance's properties immediately renders useless with the chosen approach/implementation where the thought to be protected class fields id, a, b are left  totally unprotected in the open at first place …class data_controller { id = 12; a = 10; b = 20; /* more code */ }. The same accounts for both, the log.entry getter and update setter properties; theirs implementations too are unprotected. Providing protected access only makes sense in case one can ensure covered protection all along the access path.

... the next provided example code shows an alternative which not only achieves protection all along every object's access path but also proofs that handling such security issues from the very beginning results in a much cleaner and leaner (more lightweight) design which makes parts of the code re-usable and the cod-base itself far easier to read/comprehend as well as to test and to maintain.
The example code ...

firstly makes use of just a single true private class field, an object which for any instance holds all of the latter's data.

secondly implements each of both access roots (for the update set path and the log.entry get path) as simple getters where each getter serves as entry point which forwards its object's private, protected state to reusable other functions, each function representing a single step within the entire access path.


Breaking all the functionality down like that also solves the OP's original problem of how to correctly handle the data instance in terms of this-context and true privacy.
The entry points, not only do access each the correct this, but because both are prototypal functions within the class construct each also can access the private state. Thus, implementing all involved property chains entirely as getter/setter chains allows for passing this state to wherever it is needed in order to access and change its properties.


// the only exported entity of the e.g. `data-controller` module.

class DataController {

  // - a single private `state` object which holds all needed data.
  #state = { id: 12, a: 10, b: 20 };

  // - decouple a `DataController` instance's protected state from
  //   its controlled access by providing reusable implemented and
  //   as well protected entry points for each data access path.

  // - entry point of the protected `update` **set** access path.
  get update() {
    return update(this.#state);
  }
  // - entry point of the protected `log.entry` **get** access path.
  get log() {
    return log(this.#state);
  }
}

// usage.
const data = new DataController();

console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);

data.update.a = 50;
data.update.b = 60;

console.log(data.log.entry.a);
console.log(data.log.entry.b);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
// local functions of the e.g. `data-controller` module.


// - reusable implementation of a `DataController` instance's
//   `update` method ... protected all along the access path.

function update(state) {
  return {
    set a(value) {
    
      // - provide functionality which
      //   checks/sanitizes `value`.

      state.a = value;
    },
    set b(value) {
    
      // - provide functionality which
      //   checks/sanitizes `value`.

      state.b = value;
    },
  }
}

// - reusable implementations of any `DataController` instance's
//   `log` and `entry` getters ... protected all along the access path.

function entry(state) {
  return {
    get a() {
      const { id, a } = state;

      return { id, value: a, label: 'a' };
    },
    get b() {
      const { id, b } = state;

      return { id, value: b, label: 'b' };
    },
  };
}
function log(state) {
  return {
    // - equals `log.entry` in a controlled/protected way.
    get entry() {
      return entry(state);
    },
  };
}
</script>




If you declared update, entry and log inside the class, you could also directly use private fields #id, #a and #b instead of creating another "state" object to pass around

@Bergi ... Why should one do that. They certainly do not belong there, the only things really needed are the two getter based entry points for the protected access-paths/keypath's ... data.update respectively data.log.entry. And as much as it it obvious that the OP's publicly declared id, a and b properties are a "no go", it likewise should be clear that the handling of just a single private state property which holds all the necessary values of interest, is far easier (e.g. passing it around) than the handling of 3 separate private properties.

@Bergi ... everything else can live outside the class. The implementation details of how one assembles the access-paths/keypaths should not be part of the class body itself. But in case one does, it will make the code more complicated (unnecessary complex).

I don't see why any code accessing the (private!) state of the class should live outside of the class. Maybe the class should simply expose public methods to access them, and the "access paths" with getters are just fancy syntactic sugar for calling them

Public methods out of the box are not protected from being overwritten, but getters are. The only other approach which is compact enough and totally immun against public property manipulation comes with utilizing Object.freeze as meanwhile demonstrated by @KooiInc.

@PeterSeliger I have read through your answer and comments:  Am I understanding correctly that the 'reusable implementations' are only declared once, and then the class's methods call these reusable functions? At the moment I have decided to use a function.call() format to address 'this' binding and reusability. I instantiate objects using data = dataController.default() and then operate on the object with dataController.log.entry.call(data, 'a'). I will need to consider using your class approach in order to leverage private fields.

@UnchainedLight ... 1/2 ... The helper functions log and entry are factory functions designed to accept a data structure as their sole argument. Each function returns an object that includes all necessary getters or setters to emulate the expected properties (either read-only or writable) of the target node in the data structure.

@UnchainedLight ... 2/2 ... The DataController class is implemented to manage its private state securely. It provides two distinct getters, each serving as an entry point for either the read-only log access path or the writable update access path. Each entry point forwards the internally held state to its corresponding helper function by name.

@UnchainedLight ... are there any questions left?

@PeterSeliger thank you Peter, no I have no questions on this topic at this time. I have plenty of questions about data security but they do not pertain specifically to this post.

class Parent {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this._child = {
      age: 0,
    };
  }

  // Getter for child age
  get childAge() {
    return this._child.age;
  }

  // Setter for child age
  set childAge(newAge) {
    if (typeof newAge === 'number' && newAge >= 0) {
      this._child.age = newAge;
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid age");
    }
  }
}

const parentInstance = new Parent('John');
console.log(parentInstance.childAge); 

parentInstance.childAge = 10; 
console.log(parentInstance.childAge); 


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
